# Create Thumbnail of MP3 Waveform in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mp3, waveform

I would like to create a WaveForm image from an MP3 file on my server.

I have tried using the [wavesurfer.js](http://wavesurfer-js.org) plugin. I would rather do it without a plugin, but I cannot find a tutorial or any good resources.

Now, I would like *save a thumbnail* of the waveform (from mp3 file) on my server. As wavesurfer.js uses an HTML5 Canvas, I don't know how to create a thumbnail of the waveform. How can I create a thumbnail?

Comment: Is your server-side code in JavaScript as well?

Comment: no, my server side code is php 5.6
can i not create a thumbnail from wavesurfer.js waveform with canvas?

Comment: right-click the canvas, "save-image as...", then upload it to your server?

Comment: thanks, i have a other idea. i will not longer create a wave form from mp3

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how they got audio wave  form images in the browser.
http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/blog/2013/10/audio-waveforms

This can be used to interact with, generate etc. waveform data (e.g. into JSON).
https://github.com/bbcrd/peaks.js

This can be used for drawing in the canvas.
https://github.com/bbcrd/waveform-data.js

You can created a thumbnail by scaling the canvas image down to the desired size and then uploading this to your server, although the same is true for wavesurfer.js

You can use http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp to scale canvas images. You can alter the canvas size using it's width and height properties.